# Dynamics 365 : Create related SharePoint folder for a Case under the Contact

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have enabled SharePoint integration with Dynamics 365.

When I add Documents under a Case it creates the following folder hierarchy:

Case -> Case Name+GUID ->

I want to change to

Contact -> Contact Name -> Case Name+GUI ->

I have set the following option, but doesn't seem to change anything.

[image]
[image]

Is my Contact based hierarchy achievable without customization?

Comment: I think you are facing this issue: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/235346